# SQL Query WHERE Clause in automation not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have an automation that fetches a file from the FTP and populates a Data Extension. The query is working fine if I just do select from in the automation.

One of the columns in the Data Extension is OnlineAvailability and its marked with y or n and I want to choose only available products so the ones that has assigned the y.

If I create a query with "WHERE OnlineAvailability ='Y' outside the automation, I get only the available products but when I do that in the SQL Activity within the automation it doesn't work, I get the "n" products as well.

I have attached a few screenshots for a better understanding.

If you have any additional questions please let me know

[image: This is the Data Extension]

This is my query

```
select
SkuID,
ProductCost,
OnlineAvailability

from [DataExtension]

where OnlineAvailability ='Y'
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the same query inside the automation as outside? Query activities and sql preform the same regardless on how you run them

Comment: yes, exactly the same one. Copy/paste

Comment: Targeting the same DE? E.g. you aren't running an update to the main ImportDE with one in auto (would not change anything) and then doing an overwrite to another DE with the non-automation one. That would explain why one works but the other does not.

Comment: I only run the query from the automation. The query outside the automation was just a test to see if there is something wrong with my query and I've created a new data extension for that from the existing one that is targeted in the automation. The query from the automation its an update but I cleared the records from the data extension and still got all the products and not only the available ones

Comment: @Gortonington, I have updated my question with my automation. Is there something wrong at my automation steps?

Comment: First Hello all. Nice to see you especially @Gortonington, saw you in the latest mc dev talk ;) You need two dataextensions -> one that imports the file and one that contains the result of the sql operation. The sql operation should have the option "overwrite". Furthermore make sure that you hard refresh the view on the dataextension after the automation has been running. If you do not hard refresh you will see the old data that has been in the dataextension before. Therefore make sure that you do like crtl + f5 inside the contact builder to see the dataextension refreshed.

Comment: If I create another data extension, in the automation do I just add a new SQL Query Activity after the current one?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Johannes Schapdick, I have created a second data extension and add a second sql query activity and it works.